# DNS Server Configuration problem , PTR records

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, email-server, reverse-dns

I have a server that using Windows server 2003 , and Microsoft DNS Server.
I have a problem on my DNS setting 
ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are: 
225.208.20.***.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips

In Reverse Lookup zones I add a new Zone an on this zone ptr records for DOMAINNAME , MAIL.DOMAINNAME.

But this doesn’t fix my problem and still on intoDNS.com I find that error message , therefor some of my emails can’t reach to mail servers

How Can I set PTR records for my Mail Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reverse lookup records translate IP addresses back into names. A lot of mail servers like to do this as part of anti-spam measures.

You need to request that the party authoritative for the reverse zone your email server lives in create the PTR records. That's probably your ISP. There's nothing you can do in the DNS server in your office-- the rest of the world doesn't look to that server for DNS. When the 3rd party mail servers initiate a reverse lookup request, that traffic isn't coming to your office-- it's going to ISP DNS servers.

I'd start by contacting support at your ISP.

(I'm assuming, in all of the above, that you're not the authoritative party for your reverse DNS zones, but probably just somebody hosting a mail server on the end of a point-to-point Internet connection from some random ISP.)